# JQuery $.ajax post gives error.state() "rejected"

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

I'm using the following code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: jsonData,
        success: wrapped,
        error: function (error) {
            console.info("Json post failed");
        }
    });
```

Which works fine for posting json data to my MVC4 actions.
However, I have one specific action that uses newtonsoft serialiser and a custom JsonResult.
When I call this action, I do get back the correct data, and status 200 OK.
But JQuery calls the error callback and the error.state() is "rejected"

Any ideas why this is?
I can pull the response out of the error and do: var o = eval(jsonresponse); and it gives me the data I want.

The only thing that is a bit different with this response is that .NET dates are serialized as real javascript code - new Date(0492342392).
Is that the reason why jquery calls the error callback?

Ideas?

**[edit]**

Here is the response json:

```
[{"name":"Bench Press","data":
[{"date":new Date(1372975200000),
"id":"70a7b32b-befc-45e2-a589-1eafc0149c8a",
 "bodyWeight":80.0,"reps":13,"weight":100.0}]}]
```

It seems to be the date that is making this fail, because if the data is empty, this specific call does not fail.

So what would be the correct way to return true javascript dates in json ?

Comment: Can you post a full example of the JSON being returned? It could be something as simple as json keys without quotes (required in newer browsers with native JSON support)

Comment: You json is not valid, just return the timestamp and apply new Date() client side

Comment: Ok, so the only way to do this is to traverse the entire response and replace every possible date property ?  #stoneage :-P

Comment: oh well, I reverted back to the standard .NET Json serializer and did as you said, parsed the date clientside

Comment: This might help: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The provided json is invalid, but if you want to use newtonsoft serializer in a custom JsonResult, you can add a serializer setting for datetime.

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                   {
                       ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                   };
settings.Converters.Add(new IsoDateTimeConverter()); //This is the converter that will serialize date objects to ISODateTime string.
var writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.None };
var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(settings);
serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);
```

The Output will be in ISODateTime string

```
public JsonNetResult Test()
{
    return new JsonNetResult { Data = new { Name = "John Doe", BirthDay = DateTime.Today }, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
}
```

Response:

```
{"name":"John Doe","birthDay":"2013-07-06T00:00:00+06:00"}
```

But you have to explicitly create the date object from the ISODateTime string

```
$.get('/home/test?_=' + +new Date(), function (data) { alert(new Date(data.birthDay)); });
```

hope this helps.